# What is the best approach to let C# and Python communicate for this machine learning task?

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm developing a simple game for a university project using **Unity**. This game makes use of machine learning, so I need **TensorFlow** in order to build a Neural Network (NN) to accomplish certain actions in the game depending on the prediction of the NN.

In particular my learning approach is *reinforcement learning*. I need to monitor the *states* and the *rewards* in the environment [coded in C#], and pass them to the NN [coded in Python]. Then the *prediction* [from Python code] should be sent back to the environment [to C# code].

Sadly I'm quite confused on how to let C# and Python communicate. I'm reading a lot online but nothing really helped me. Can anybody clear my ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Which OS are you using? You can just run Python scripts from C# as system commands.

Comment: @EmmetB thanks for this answer, I'm using MacOS. Ok, I understand so I may run a Python script from C# code sending informations to my NN. But I don't have any idea on how to transfer the prediction made, back to my C# code, for now, but that's another story. I may look for how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results

Comment: If you're allowed to, you may use the UnityML library. It's pretty easy to set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

#### Subprocess

You can open the python script via the Unity's C# then send stdout and stdin data to and from the process. In the Python side it's as simple as `input()` and `print()`, and in the C# side it's basically reading and writing from a `Stream` object (as far as I remember)

#### UDP/TCP sockets

You can make your Python a UDP/TCP server (preferrably UDP if you have to transfer a lot of data, and it might be simpler to code). Then you create a C# client and send requests to the Python server. The python server will do the processing (AI magic, yayy!) then return the results to the Unity's C#. In C# you'd have to research the `UdpClient` class, and in Python, the `socket` module.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It's an interesting approach. I'm going to try it and I'll let you know.

Comment: Glad to hear! Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 3):

On thing for inter-process communication that is definitely worth looking at is **(Win32) named pipes**. It is almost as easy as writing to or reading from files. Easier than TCP/IP and you can even communicate over the local network, at least if you have the access rights. Add your own serialization code and your done.

It is a little asymmetric though (in one direction you just open a file with the name of the pipe, in the opposite direction you have to create a named pipe object, don't remember which is which).

For example see  [Example of Named Pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806153/example-of-named-pipes)

If you google for "named pipes windows" you will find loads of information. But remember not to use anonymous pipes (they are ugly).

Comment: That's a very useful solution I omitted in purpose from my answer. From my experience, many just find it difficult, for some reason. But it's definitely worth a shot as it's (theoretically) simpler than my solutions.

Comment: Yeah, I remember that I had to do some research back then, but it's worth it in my opinion.

Comment: Which method has the least overhead : UDP/TCP connection or Named pipes?

Comment: @KaranJoisher: If you are using pipes over the local network then they are transported by tcp, so they definitely have higher overhead than using tcp directly. On the same machine they seem to be about the same. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872557/how-slow-are-tcp-sockets-compared-to-named-pipes-on-windows-for-localhost-ipc

Comment: So if on the same machine TCP and named pipes are giving similar performance then between TCP and UDP which would be better? Cause data transmission for my appication needs to be real time so it seems UDP should be the preferred choice

Comment: @KaranJoisher: I'm afraid I don't know. If I were you, I would just test it with some simple example.

Answer (score 2):

You can integrate the compiled DLL from C#   natively with python using Python for .NET  [(pythonnet)](http://pythonnet.github.io/)

pythonnet is a package that gives Python programmers nearly seamless integration with the .NET 4.0+ Common Language Runtime (CLR) on Windows and Mono runtime on Linux and OSX.

Using this package you can script .NET applications or build entire applications in Python, using .NET services and components written in any language that targets the CLR (C#, VB.NET, F#, C++/CLI).

Installation

```
    pip install pythonnet
```

using compiled class library My.dll in python:

```
    import clr
    clr.AddReference("My.DLL")
    # call methods in dll
```

See a [working example](https://python-catalin.blogspot.com.eg/2017/05/using-python-for-net-clr-python-module.html)

pythonnet  in  [github](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet)

How to use the package in python [WIKI](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Unity Machine learning agent, then connecting C# code and python is not that hard.

The mlagents Python package contains two components: a low-level API which allows you to interact directly with a Unity Environment (mlagents_envs) and an entry point to train (mlagents-learn) which allows you to train agents in Unity Environments using our implementations of reinforcement learning or imitation learning.
Follow this documentation for more details https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/docs/Training-ML-Agents.md

Answer (score -1):

Run with ML.NET C# code a TensorFlow model exported from Azure Cognitive Services Custom Vision. f[or more information](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/run-with-ml-net-c-code-a-tensorflow-model-exported-from-azure-cognitive-services-custom-vision/)

Comment: Hello Hailu, Stack Overflow recommends against providing an answer via a hyperlink, since if the link gets broken, the answer has no more value. Please try and add some more explanation to your answer about how it solves the problem.