# NAMED PIPES sql server

Tags: sql-server-2000

i know Named Pipes are Protocols. but i have not seen even 1 example how to use them?

can u tell me what are the Named pipes ?

Answer (score 0):

Named pipes are one of many interprocess communication protocol. I think the wikipedia entry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipes explain them well.

In sql-server named pipes are one of the method of communication between the client and the server, you could specify a connection string that use named pipes to get to the server.

See also this question: [What are named pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175579/what-are-named-pipes)