# Read/write linux named pipe (fifo) in Windows

Tags: c#, linux, windows, fifo, smb

I would like to read and write a fifo created in Linux on an SMB share from an application in Windows using C#.  It seems that if I try to read from the pipe as if it were a normal file using `StreamReader` directly, it reaches the end of the stream without actually retrieving any data.  If I try using `NamedPipeClientStream`, it throws an `IOException` stating `A volume has been accessed for which a file system driver is required that has not yet been loaded.` This makes me think maybe this isn't doable. Are Named Pipes in Windows completely different from Linux? If so, can I treat this as a normal file?

Here is the code I used first:

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"\\mvssuperos7\shared\lread");
String line;
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}

file.Close();
Console.WriteLine("Finished");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Pretty straightforward; from the Linux system, I have a text file with several lines of nonsense which I `cat` to the pipe.  This blocks, as I would expect it to, then I run the listed code, which prints "Finished" as if it reached the end of the stream.  This also unblocks `cat` on the Linux end, which I find precarious.

Here is the code I used with `NamedPipeClientStream`:

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"\\mvssuperos7\shared\lread");
using (NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient =
new NamedPipeClientStream(@"mvssuperos7", "shared/lread", PipeDirection.In))
{

// to the pipe or wait until the pipe is available.
Console.Write("Attempting to connect to pipe...");
pipeClient.Connect();

Console.WriteLine("Connected to pipe.");
Console.WriteLine("There are currently {0} pipe server instances open.",
pipeClient.NumberOfServerInstances);
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeClient))
{
    // Display the read text to the console
    string temp;
    while ((temp = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Received from server: {0}", temp);
    }
}
```

This is what is throwing the Exception -- I'm assuming Windows Named Pipes are not what I'm looking for here, I'll have to read more about them. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Linux pipes are not Windows pipes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960221/windows-named-pipe-support-in-Linux. Why did the streamreader not work? Or did it?

Comment: The streamreader seems to immediately reach the end of the stream, regardless of what I send through the pipe. I'm not sure if I'm making a mistake in my code or if this type of thing just won't work.

Comment: What I read up to now, fifo Linux pipes only live in memory, so no content is written to disk. With your StreamReader you're reading the disk.

Comment: Hmm I suppose this probably won't be possible then

Comment: Unless the SMB service (Samba?) explicitly supports doing this, it almost certainly won't work.