# Host Node.js Socket.io as Azure app

Tags: node.js, azure, socket.io, azure-web-app-service

I create Node.js Socket.io app with Visual Studio. It works fine locally.
When I publish it as Azure app getting error:

"The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Does anybody know what is the problem, I am thinking about port 80 which is only open port for Azure app (+ 443).

I tried to listen to port 80 , but again the same error.

Comment: When I hosted a socket.io app on Azure I had to use the Azure app that was specifically for "Node.JS applications"

Comment: Did you create it from Azure dashboard, instead of Visual Studio create it by default when publish?

Comment: Yes I created the Node.js app from the Azure dashboard, and then if I remember correctly, used a specific GIT deployment URL that I put into VS

Comment: Can you please tell me the template name? Thanks!

Comment: There is an option when you create a "New" item in Azure: Node JS Empty Web App. Also check here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-web/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac.md 

I used the GIT url to deploy from VS

Comment: Thank you very much, problem solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build a socket.io application on Azure Web Apps, there are several attentions you should pay on:

- Node.js server listening `port should be set similar to`process.env.PORT || 3000`
- Verify web.config settings, confirm `<webSocket enabled="false"/>` to disable the IIS WebSockets module, which includes its own implementation of WebSockets and conflicts with Node.js specific WebSocket modules such as Socket.IO.

Please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-chat-app-socketio/ for more details.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Liu , I need to create a file known as web.config and need to add `<webSocket enabled="false"/>` to disable IIS? My app is using polling instead of WebSockets, please help me...

Answer (score 1):

Azure App Service uses **IISNode** to talk to **node.exe** processes. This happens over named pipes.
Configure your application to use the named pipe instead of a socket.

i.e.

Replace

```
app.set('port', 3000);
```

by

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

<del>Enable **WebSockets** in the Portal, restart the Web App and you should be up and running.</del>

[ **Gary Liu** is right, that setting is not needed. However using a sample Socket.IO chat implementation on App Service, Socket.IO doesn't seem to care about how i set "WebSockets" in the portal. Works either way.  ]

Since *Internal Server Error* is the computing equivalent to *There is a fault in the observable Universe* you should also enable logging for your Node application, at least for the development phase:
From https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-debug/:

> To enable developer errors, add the following line to the IISNode.yml file:
>
> `devErrorsEnabled: true`
>
> Once this option is enabled, IISNode will return the last 64K of information sent to stderr instead of a friendly error such as "an internal server error occurred".

More on iisnode: http://www.jokecamp.com/blog/getting-started-with-iisnode/
More on named pipes: [What are named pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175579/what-are-named-pipes)

Comment: Thank you! My Azure app is live now.