# Socket vs. multiprocessing.connection.Listener in python

Tags: python, sockets, multiprocessing, ipc, python-multiprocessing

I know there are different ways to implement `IPC` in python such as `Pipes` and `Queue`; But according to the Python's official documentation, There is also an alternative way called [Listener and Client](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.connection).

`multiprocessing.connection.Listener` is much like `socket` and both got same functions like `accept()` , `close()` , `send()` and `recv()`. So if we **only** focus on IPC purpose , whats difference between these two modules?
Which one is more efficient ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Socket Families

I looked at [cpython on github](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/connection.py#L437), `multiprocessing.connection.Listener` uses `socket` standard library with just one main different point : socket families.

`Listeners` support these families for communication :

- [`AF_PIPE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/175669/11879944) - Named pipe
- `AF_INET` - TCP socket
- `AF_UNIX` - Unix domain socket

Python's standard `socket` library supports `AF_INET` and `AF_UNIX` well, so we can surely say that the main difference is about `AF_PIPE` family.